# How do I create persistant TCPSockets?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I have a server which sends two messages to the client in a row:

```
require 'socket'
require 'thread'
connections = []
server = TCPServer.new(9998)
loop do
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    client.print 'Once'
    client.print 'Upon a time.'
  end #eo Thread
end #eo infinte loop
```

The client is:

```
require 'socket'
client = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 9998)
2.times { print client.read }
client.close
```

The client 'stands suspended' until I shut down the server, and only then prints out the messages. I know adding `client.close` to the server would fix the suspension, but I don't want to close the socket.

I know some applications reuse a TCPSocket. So, it can be `Client > Server`, `Server > Client`, `Client > Server x2`, and so on. I am sure there's a way to do that in Ruby; I just can't figure out how.

So, my list of questions is:

1. How do I create a persistant Server <-> Client connection, as described above?
2. Is there a better way of keeping a server open without using `loop`?
3. Why does it stay suspended like that without `client.close` in the server? Does the server buffer the messages before it sends them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. How does one create a persistant Server <-> Client connection,as described above.

You've got several choices: you can write a threaded server, where a single 'process' with mostly shared memory executes multiple threads of execution, and each thread has some thread-local storage for e.g. `client`. Or, you could write a multi-process server, where each client connection gets its own independent process via `fork(2)` (which pretty much means it runs on Unix-only, as Windows attempts to implement `fork(2)` never work well). Or, you could write an event-loop based state machine, and use `select(2)` or `poll(2)` or `epoll(4)` to manage which clients are readable, writable, and have errors.

Choosing between them might seem difficult, [but there are guidelines available](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html). I'd like to suggest that -small- systems, where you're only expected to have 20-30 simultaneous clients, can be very well handled via threaded or forked servers. If you wish to go beyond that number of simultaneous clients, you should use a tool like [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki) or [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) to write your server. (Which may or may not be easier to maintain anyway.)

> 2) Is there a better way of keeping a server open, without using loop [because I feel like I've commited murder by creating an endless loop]

Endless loops are quite fine :) but sometimes it makes sense to offer a way to restart servers or terminate them via `signal(7)`s or specialized command interfaces.

> 3) Why does it stay suspended like that without client.close in the server? Does the server buffer the messages before it sends them?

Ah, **here** is the question you really needed -- TCP will try to *buffer* the results of multiple packets from the server, and due to the potential need to fragment too-large packets mid-route, you, as a client, have *no guarantees* that any kind of datagram boundaries are preserved.

Chances are *very* good that your server's TCP/IP stack waited a tiny bit before sending the first packet to see if more data is coming soon. (It often does.) It probably coalesced the *two* calls to `client.print()` into a single TCP packet. Your client calls `client.read()` *twice*, but there is probably only enough data for *one* read. If you wanted your TCP stream to send the first packet *immediately*, you could look into setting the `TCP_NODELAY` socket option to disable this small delay. (But it might not help all on its own; you might need to use it in conjunction with `TCP_CORK` to try to "bottle up" all the writes until you explicitly flush them. This is probably an awful idea.)

A better option would be to re-write your client to be aware of the *protocol* between your server and client; it needs to read input into a buffer, parse the buffer to find 'complete messages', consume those messages, and then return to its main event loop.

Maybe your protocol is to read / write ASCII or UTF-8 terminated with `"\n"` characters; in that case, you can change `print` to `puts` or add the `\n` in the right places, and change `read()` to `readline()`. (This would let the standard IO library handle your protocol for you.) Another approach would be to send data with length+data pairs, and await the correct length of data.

Comment: I must say, that reading your response was as much a pleasure as it was resourceful and useful. Thanks <3

Comment: @with a dot., thanks :) I particularly loved `I feel like I've committed murder by creating an endless loop`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use puts instead. And use socket.flush if you want to male sure it's sent. It buffers the data otherwise.

Comment: What if, though, I wanted to use binary transfer (considering that; I'm a nut case). Wouldn't print be the better option, then? Also, (maybe I'm wrong, about what I'm about to say) will read work with puts? Won't I have to use gets? O:

Comment: socket.sync=true or flush after each write.